Lazy loading component not render in view source page Angular14 ssr
i have recently integrate ssr in angular14 (client to ssr),when i integarte lazyloading in component its works fine locally means routing works fine in view source page lazyload component render correctly in <app-root> but on server its not working for e.g  </a></div></div></div></app-header><router-outlet _ngcontent-sc283=""></router-outlet><!----><app-footer _ngcontent-sc283="" _nghost-sc282=""> in router-outlet my lazyload component content not rendering in view source page, how i can fix this issue?
I have try intialnavigation in app-routing but its not work also try to add maploadermodular but its deprecated my expectation is my lazyload component content  should  render in view source page
